# Google Experiments - Variations by region

Tags: ab-testing, google-experiments

Is it possible in Google Experiments to not split the variations based on a percentage, and instead have certain IP ranges or region codes go to specific regions?

What is being requested at work is to have 6 variations, 2 for each region, and the original. I would first identify the region, and then do an even split between the original and the 2 variations.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible. We instead came up with a split table for variation splitting and use custom reports to roll the original page and "original experiment" pages together.

[image]